# Unhide Named Range when entered in cell

Tags: google-apps-script

I have 52 named ranges, from W1 to W52. I would like to have my Google Sheet worksheet hide all rows except the named range that I input in cell B1 and row 1 itself so I can keep toggling between the named ranges to unhide. For example, if I put "W1" into cell B1, only row 1 and all rows within the named range W1 will unhide while the rest remain hidden.

Is this possible? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do your named range overlap?

Comment: Nope, they don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work:
I assume you have no other function named onEdit(). If you do then you have to combine them logically into one function. This may be a lot of function for an onEdit trigger because I think you only have 30 seconds before script timeout on triggers. When your writing to the screen it just takes a lot of time.

```
function onEdit()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=="Sheet1")//It will only do this on Sheet1
  {
  var lr=sh.getLastRow();
  var name=sh.getRange('B1').getValue();
  sh.hideRows(2, lr-1);
  var allRanges=ss.getNamedRanges();
  var rows=[];
  for(var i=0;i<allRanges.length;i++)
  {
    if(allRanges[i].getName()==name)
    {
      var rgi=allRanges[i].getRange();
      var toprow=rgi.getRow();
      var numrows=rgi.getNumRows();
      sh.showRows(toprow, numrows);
      break;
    }
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper, thank you. It only works when I run the script in script editor. In the actual workbook, if I change the value in cell B1, it's does nothing. Sorry. My first time working with script.

Comment: You'll need an onEdit trigger for that. You can create a simple trigger by simply changing the name of the function to onEdit. This assumes that you have no other function named onEdit.

Comment: Amazing this work perfectly. But because the onEdit function affects any active sheet and any cell I edit, if I edit a cell on a separate sheet on the same workbook, it triggers the function. Is there a way to limit the function to have effect on the specific sheet named "Schedule" and only when I edit cell B1 on said sheet? You have been tremendously helpful.

Comment: Yes. You can wrap the function with an if statement like after the var sh= line and limit it to a given sheet name and perhaps range

Comment: Now it will only do it on Sheet1.  You can add other conditions as well.  Look [here for the special information passed with the event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).

Comment: Hi Cooper, your method works well. I'm still struggling to get it to trigger onEdit only when changes are made to the specific cell despite some feeble attempts.

Comment: I'm currently using a button to run the script which works well since I am still unable to find the solution to having the script only trigger when editing cell B1 on Sheet1. However, this has limitations because buttons don't work when you're working on mobile devices. Would appreciate if anyone has a fix to make my onEdit trigger work right and remove the need for a physical button on the sheet to run the script.

Comment: Please post your code and if possible give us link to your spreadsheet.

Comment: Hi Cooper, I used your exact code except that I changed the first line to function onClick() and attached it to a button drawing. I'll try to put up a link to it but I'll need to remove some stuff first since it has some data. It's for a school project.